# Constructors testing for strange in-stack value

Tags: disassembly, x86, c++

This is something that I found in a lot of constructors that have to do with classes that inherit from other classes. I have a vague idea as to why it's done, but I'd rather have it confirmed before having to re-visit all of my classes.

Say I have a constructor with a known signature e.g. `CPalette()`. The compiler turn this into a `CPalette * __thiscall CPalette::CPalette(CPalette* this)`, with `this` being in ecx. Hence, no values need to be retrieved from the stack. However, when the constructor is called, it looks something like this:

```
// with allocated memory in eax
PUSH   0x01
MOV    ecx, eax
CALL   CPalette::CPalette
```

Inside the constructor, this value is then used in a test:

```
// start of constructor
PUSH   -0x01
PUSH   label_1
MOV    eax, fs:[0x00]                  // question for another day
PUSH   eax
MOV    dword ptr fs:[0x00], esp        
SUB    esp ,0x8
MOV    eax, dword ptr [esp + 18]       // Ghidra: ... [esp + Stack[0x04]]
PUSH   esi
MOV    esi, ecx
PUSH   edi
TEST   eax, eax
MOV    dword ptr [esp + 0x08], esi     // Ghidra: ... [esp + local_14]
MOV    dword ptr [esp + 0x18], 0x00    // Ghidra: ... [esp + local_4]
JZ     label_2
```

I'm also a bit confused about Ghidra's auto-analysis, which I've attached to the end of the respective lines. The decompilation uses the name `in_stack_00000004` for the `TEST`ed register.

Why do we push a 1 on the stack and what is the test doing?
My best guess is that this is a way to know if the constructor is called directly or by a child class constructor, since I've seen some `PUSH 0x00`s before constructor calls inside other constructors. If this is the case, why is this done?

This is from a 32 bit windows DLL.

Comment: Do you have RTTI? Does this class inherit another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, the class participates in a virtual inheritance tree. When constructing a class with virtual bases, the constructor needs to know whether its virtual bases have been already constructed or not. The extra argument is used for that. If you compile a sample program with virtual inheritance and look at its [assembly output](https://godbolt.org/z/e6cTajqf3), you'll see that it's called 'initVBases' (i.e. "initialize virtual bases").

```
_this$ = -4                                   ; size = 4
_$initVBases$ = 8                                 ; size = 4
button::button(void) PROC                              ; button::button, COMDAT
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        push    ecx
        mov     DWORD PTR _this$[ebp], ecx
        cmp     DWORD PTR _$initVBases$[ebp], 0
        je      SHORT $LN2@button
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _this$[ebp]
        mov     DWORD PTR [eax], OFFSET const button::`vbtable'
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR _this$[ebp]
        add     ecx, 8
        call    control::control(void)
$LN2@button:
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR _this$[ebp]
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [ecx]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [edx+4]
        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR _this$[ebp]
        mov     DWORD PTR [ecx+eax], OFFSET const button::`vftable'
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR _this$[ebp]
        mov     esp, ebp
        pop     ebp
        ret     4
button::button(void) ENDP                              ; button::button
```

In case the binary has RTTI (Run-time Type Information), you should be able to confirm it by inspecting the [RTTI structures](http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/23).

Comment: This confirms what I've been suspecting, thanks! I should have made it more clear that yes, this class is part of an inheritance tree. IIRC the binary has RTTI, I should start looking at that as well.